Next.js 14 next-intl default language slug problem
in next.js 14, for example, I want the default language to appear as / instead of /en. For another example, I want it to appear as /blogs instead of /en/blogs. In my codes, the default language is set to tr and the second language is set to en, but /tr comes at the beginning. I want the letters of the default language not to appear.
middleware.js
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

export default createMiddleware({
  locales: ["tr", "en"],
  localeDetection: false,

  defaultLocale: "tr",
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/(tr|en)/:path*"],
};

i18n.ts
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getRequestConfig } from "next-intl/server";

// Can be imported from a shared config
export const locales = ["tr", "en"];

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
  // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  if (!locales.includes(locale as any)) notFound();

  return {
    messages: (await import(`./messages/${locale}.json`)).default,
  };
});

layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from "next-intl";
import { getMessages } from "next-intl/server";
import NavbarTest from "../../components/navbar";

// import Navbar from "@/components/navbar";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
}>) {
  const messages = await getMessages();

  return (
    <NextIntlClientProvider messages={messages}>
      <html lang={locale}>
        <body className={`antialiased flex flex-col min-h-screen`}>
          {/* <Navbar locale={locale} /> */}
          <NavbarTest locale={locale} />
          <div className="flex-1">{children}</div>
        </body>
      </html>
    </NextIntlClientProvider>
  );
}

